Visual Studio Code files disappeared in Folder
I am quite new in coding and while I was doing some exercises on CSS on Mac, all my files disappeared from folder section. I don't know how to bring them back and to have the folder option available again. Thank you for your help.enter image description here
I have searched on the internet and on settings but I could not find a way to restore them

Looks like it's just collapsed. Try clicking near > to expand a section, i.e. "2.2 ...".

2.2 was only one I was able to open, but I had like 20/25 folders that now I cannot see. When I click on the 3 dots of explorer, folder is not highlighted, and I cannot select it
